# Clear console log in browser using protractor

Tags: protractor

I'm able to retrieve the browser logs using

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
   logger.info('log: ' + require('util').inspect(browserLog));
});
```

referenced from https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md

Similarly is there a way to clear the browser console logs?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about why do you need this - the motivation behind the question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
function clearLogs() {
    browser.manage().logs().get('browser');
}
```

Retrieving the logs the way you do actually clears the collection so that trying to get them immediately after that returns an empty array.

Comment: Nice! Works in ruby as well (not with the same syntax of-course).